# relative path in project not working

Tags: web-config, log4net, relative-path

I have a project folder that goes in this format

C:\Users\koh\Desktop\RFolder\trunk\MML\MML-web\mweb\mweb-web\meweb.vbproj - location of my vbproj file and web.config file

I have a log4net file in the following location

C:\Users\koh\Desktop\RFolder\trunk\MML\Common\Configuration\log4net.config

I would like to map in my web.config file the location to my log4net config file.

```
    <arg key="configFile" value="/../../../Common/Configuration/log4net.config"/>
```

However this doesnt seem to work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: you need to get rid of that first `/`

Comment: doesn't seem to solve the problem

Comment: how are you using the `configFile` setting in your code?

Comment: use `<arg key="configFile" value="..\..\..\Common\Configuration\log4net.config"/>`

Answer (score -1):

For windows, you need \ instead of /. You may also need \\ instead of \ to get it to work.

Comment: quite confused by \\ instead of \, can u please give me an example

Comment: `\' isn't really required .net will interpret both correctly